# get many different signals through one wire

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit

I am new here. I want something done, and I strongly believe there is an IC for this job, but I don't know what it is called and I can't get the right words into google. What I want is to take many electrical signals and have them pulse in a single file line, sort of to speak. This is for sending information to a computer via USB, I would also like to know of a way to separate singles by time, like chop up a 1 second pulse into 10 bits, with the idea that I will be sending 10 signals per second.

I plan on hooking up a bunch of Potentiometers to a usb port on a computer. The Potentiometers will be attached to a skeleton figure and will tell me the rotation of a bone at any given time. I will be making the software reading the Potentiometers.

Comment: The search term you're looking for is multiplexing.

Comment: You can't "hook up" a potentiometer to USB. If you tell us how you plan to make a potentiometer talk USB, maybe someone can give you better help. Your question as it stands is pretty vague. Maybe what you are looking for is simply a handful of the cheapest Arduino boards, connected to an USB hub.

Comment: @MattYoung  The abyss he is peering into...  No, wrong, too Nietzsche... I meant to say: the term he is looking at is either *microcontroller* or *DAQ*.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yeah, stopped reading the question after the first 2 lines. Not in the mood to dispell misconceptions.

Comment: Have you considered using absolute rotary encoders, instead of pots, to read the angles on the skeleton? With the pots you'll need to provide a buffer circuit to make sure there isn't interaction between 2 different 'joints'. Do you plan on moving more than one joint at the same time?

Comment: @philbrooksjazz This is the first time I am hearing about Absolute Rotary Encoders, -_- I already have 10 pots on the way. I do plan on moving more then one joint at a time.

Comment: You just need to make sure that when you move 2 or more joints at a time, the readings don't interact with each other.  I don't mean to get to far off your main topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is **multiplexer**, there are many different types of muliplexing

time division and frequency division are two common types of multiplexing.

you appear to be describing time division mulplexing in your description,

It seems to me you really only need a USB extender and a USB hub on the end to connect your devices to, USB uses a complicated form of time division multiplexing internally.

hoever if you want to build your own system you want to **serialize** the data at the source end an **deserialize** is at the other end.  there are SERDES chips designed to do this sort of stuff but ther are likely a million times too fast.

for analogue signals like potentiometers you might find something useful in radio control encoders, these encode potentiometers to a time division multiplexed PWM signal, you can probably decode it using a sound-card and specialized software.

Comment: I plan on hooking up a bunch of Potentiometers to the usb, would a USB extender + hub work well with that?

Comment: yeah, but you still need something to convert the optentiometer output to usb input.  anything that would work over a short usb cable should work over a usb extender,  but you can't go much past 20m this way.

Comment: Wait, I am planing on having around 64 Pots on my build, high number, I know. By hub do you mean the things that let me plug more then one usb in at a time, or is there a component I have not heard of?

Comment: You will need Analog-to-Digital converters to read the pot outputs and convert the analog value to a digital value that can be sent via a digital-to-USB interface.  You will almost certainly need one or more microcontrollers somewhere.

Comment: I have been looking up ADCs for an hour now, I feel like I need a degree to know how to use them -_-

Comment: probably yow want a chip that has USB one one "side" and several DACs on the other FTDI's FT51A looks ideal but seems to be mythical.

Comment: the question has drifted from originlly 10 undefined inputs described as "bits"  to now 64 analogue inputs, the above approach is probably less than ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Try use one of these -- https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html . It has 21 analog input channels (i.e. voltage can be read with the on-board ADC). You can connect 21 pots to those, and write a relatively simple program to read each one with the ADC, and send the data over the built-in USB to the host PC.

Pots are not intended for precision uses, so even an 8-bit ADC will be perfectly adequate for nearly any use like this.

Now -- you need to decide what to do with the data on the PC -- in the simplest form, you might export data from the Teensy as a repeating list of values with Pot#, value:

01:1.234
02:2.321
03:0.999
etc.

Then the PC can read that data relatively simply.

If you need more input channels, you can 
  a) get some analog switches (e.g. CD4066), and connect each POT in turn to a channel (with 64 pots, you'd need ~ 16 of those ICs; each has 4 switches).
  b) get 5 Teensy's; program 4 of them each for ~ 16 pots, and connect all 4 to a 5th with either SPI, I2C or serial. Then have the 5th act as the interface to the PC/USB. The programming for this will be more complex, but it scales to a huge number of pots, and the hardware is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are trying to read a bunch of pots, forget your description of pulses through USB. USB does not support analog transmission - it is purely digital. What you need is called a Data Acquisition system (DAQ). This will consist of a box with several input channels. Software on the PC will communicate with the box(es), which will repetitively convert inputs to digital values (analog to digital conversion) and send the digital values to the PC. You can get DAQs in various sizes. The most common is 8 channels of 12 bit accuracy. However, you can get DAQs with as many as 32 analog channels.

Since you'll be using multiple DAQs, you'll need to plug them into a USB hub.

And this will cost you. National Instruments is probably the biggest DAQ manufacturer, and their stuff does not come cheap. You can look on eBay. You can also find no-name Chinese units for much less money, but caveat emptor applies as always.

Comment: something like this? http://www.ebay.com/itm/No-Driver-USB-I-O-DAQ-Control-Module-16-Channel-MCU-I-O-Pin-/171417369099?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368

Comment: Nope. That is an IO module. It provides 16 digital inputs or outputs. To read pots requires A/D converters.

Answer (score 0):

Several people have commented that you may be looking for a multiplexer, but I think you might also be interested in a "serial converter". You can think of a multiplexer as a [railroad turntable](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/turntable-railroad-13186958.jpg), which can align one channel (track) to a large number of tracks.

In reading your question, though, I don't think you're asking about how to "line up" one signal wire to many signal wires, but instead on how to *build* the signal (train) to begin with. That is, a railroad turntable aligns a train, and the train itself is the series of pulses.

Serial communications use *serial* data - data in series. Unlike parallel communications, where all the bits are sent at the same time, serial communications "stack up" bits *in a line* (like a train), to send them down a few wires.

Typically a serial communication bus will use a one-directional line for outgoing data, a one-directional line for incoming data, and a synchronizing line so each end can agree on where one bit stops and another starts. Back to the train analogy, you wouldn't want outgoing and incoming trains on the same track - the cars (bits) would collide and mangle your people (message).

Different serial protocols have different setups, but that's generally what you're looking for. Fortunately for you, I think (basically) every microcontroller should be capable of reading and writing to serial on its own, so then if you're just trying to get a widget you made to talk to USB then you would just need a [serial to USB adapter](https://www.google.com/search?&tbm=shop&q=serial+to+usb+adapter)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is 2 components:

1. An analog multiplexer - a time division mux that will 'poll' the analog levels on the network of pots into a single analog signal. The output (on a scope) will look like a bunch of different DC levels 'chopped up'.
2. A analog to digital converter (ADC) to convert the muxed signal into a digital signal to be sent over USB.

However - I think a much easier solution is to find an off-the-shelf USB A to D module, I googled this and found the DataQ DI-149, very low cost data acquisition starter kit, $59. 8 analog inputs, + 3 digital inputs. 
www.dataq.com/products/di-149/

Also MicroDAQ, Digi-Key, and National Instruments make similar products.

You'll get the AD hardware, USB interface, software drivers, and probably example code also.

Google "low cost USB digital to analog modules"

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description where and how you need to concentrate the data. There are several terms that could be relevant:

- **SERDES (serialize/deserialize):** If you have a group of parallel digital signals (such as a CPU data bus) and you want to send them all over a smaller number of wires, you can serialize them on one end and deserialize them on the other. This is usually done at very high speeds (hundreds of megabits per second) in complex digital systems like cell phones, so it's probably not what you want.
- **Multiplexing:** If you want to select one signal out of a group, you can use a multiplexer (or "mux" for short). There are both analog and digital muxes, though the control signals for the selection are always digital. The opposite of multiplexing is demultiplexing, in which a single input is connected to one of several outputs. You could use this along with a clock and various other digital elements to build a SERDES system, but that's needlessly low-level, so it's probably not what you want.
- **Multi-channel analog to digital conversion:** Analog to digital converters (especially on microcontrollers) often come with a built-in analog mux front-end that allows several analog inputs to be sampled sequentially. If you're not sure what to do with your potentiometer voltages, this might be what you want.
- **Serial communication:** There are various higher-level protocols for sending bytes of digital data over a small number of wires. You're already using USB on the PC side, which supports a variety of options for organizing data streams. You could use one endpoint per potentiometer if your USB controller supports that many endpoints. Or you could create your own data packet format. If your "potentiometers" are actually sensors with serial communication built in, you should use whatever protocol they do.

I suspect that what you really want is a microcontroller with a multi-channel ADC and a USB controller built in. The microcontroller can read the potentiometer states via the ADC, then send that information to the PC over USB. You'll probably need a higher-end part to get enough ADC channels.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems what you really want is a concentrator,  you want 64 inputs on one end and a PC on the other end. read rate seems to be non-critical, perhaps once per second or only 10 reading per second.

here's one approach.

create an 8x8 matrix of variable-resistor and diode, (like a switch-diode matrix but with variable resistor instead.
have the cathodes of the diodes point to rows and the anodes towards the columns.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOAHEv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then find a microcontroller with 8 inbuilt ADCs maybe "Arduino" or "BASIC Stamp"

arrange to drive the rows high one at a time and on the end of the columns put a current sink designed to sink the current that the resistor can provide at maximum resistance

connect that point to the DAC input too

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBKdrb.png)</sup>

With R1 above eaqual to the vairable resistor max resistance the voltage seen at the DAC will vary linearly with the variable resistor setting from about 0.7V to almost the drive voltage - 0.7

now program the microcontroller to drive the columns high one at a time and for each row read all the ADCs and send the send the ADC output out the serial port to the PC where it is read either via the arduino's USB interface or via some other type of serial port.